# Coefficients of $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k)$

Tags: polynomials, summation, products

I'm interested in the coefficients of $x$ in the expansion of,

$$ (x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k) = x^k + P_1(k) x^{k-1} + P_2(k)x^{k-2} + \cdots + P_k(k),$$

Where $k$ is an integer. In particular I am interested in thinking of these coefficients as polynomials in $k$.

Its not to hard to show that,

$$ P_1(k) = -\sum_{i=1}^k i =-k(k-1)/2 $$
 $$ P_2(k) = \sum_{i=2}^k i \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} j = k^4/8 + k^3/12-k^2/8-k/12$$

And I am pretty sure that $$ P_n(k) = (-1)^k\sum_{i_1=n}^k i_1 \sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1-1}i_2 \sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2-1}i_3\cdots i_{n-1}\sum_{i_n=1}^{i_{n-1}-1}i_n$$

I haven't gotten around to proving it but it works for $P_1$, $P_2$ and $P_3$ which gives me some confidence in the formula. For the purpose of this question assume that the formula works in general.

The last polynomial is a bit awkward because $P_k(k) = (-1)^kk!$ meaning that the coefficients are heavily dependent upon $k$ and somewhat ill defined. However I am primarily interested in $P_n$ when $n<k$.

My questions are the following,

- Is there a simple formula for the coefficients of $P_n(k)$.
- Is there a tight upper bound $M_k \geq P_n(x)$ for $x=1,2,\ldots,k$ which holds for all $n$.
- I would also be interested in an upper bound on the coefficients if their explicit form is unavailable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the [Stirling  numbers of the first kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind).

> By definition they are the coefficients in the expansion
>
> $(x)_n = \sum_{k=0}^n s(n,k) x^k,$
>
> where $(x)_n$ is the falling factorial
>
> $(x)_n = x(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n+1).$

So  $P_n(k)=s(n+1,k).$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
\sum_{k = 0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k} = \sum_{k = 0}^{n}\left[k!\,a_{k}\right]\,{x^{k} \over k!} 
$$
Then,
$$
a_{k}
=
\left.{1 \over k!}\totald[k]{\pars{\sum_{k = 0}^{n}a_{k}x^{k}}}{x}
\right\vert_{x\ =\ 0}
$$
In your case, the 'simple formula' you are looking for is given by:
$$
P_{i}
=
\left.
{1 \over \pars{k - i}!}\totald[k - i]{\bracks{\pars{x - 1}\ldots\pars{x - k}}}{x}
\right\vert_{x\ =\ 0}
$$