# On the coefficients of $(x-1)...(x-(p-1))$

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

It seems that all coefficients, except the first and the last one, of the polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)...(x-(p-1))$, where $p$ is a prime, are divisible by $p$. Example for $p=7$:

$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-5)(x-6) = x^6 - 21 x^5 + 175 x^4 - 735 x^3 + 1624 x^2 - 1764 x + 720$

The coefficients 21, 175, 735, 1624, 1764 are all divisible by 7.

How to prove this for all $p$?

The coefficient of $x^{p-2}$ is $-(1 + 2 + ... + (p-1)) = -p(p-1)/2$ which is divisible by $p$ for $p>2$. (For $p=2$ the corresponding polynomial is $x-1$, which does not have any coefficients except the first and last one.) Is there a general formula for the coefficients of this kind of polynomial with roots 1, ..., $(p-1)$ (from which the divisibility follows)?

Comment: I am not sure about such a formula but divisibility by $p$ of the coefficients follows by using that the degree $p$ polynomial $x^p-x$ has the $p$ roots $0,1,...p-1$ in the field $\mathbb{Z}$ mod $p$, so $x(x-1)…(x-(p-1))=x^p-x$ modulo $p$

Comment: These coefficients are called [Stirling numbers of the first kind](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs2800/2013fa/Handouts/Stirling.pdf), if you want to go hunting for divisibility properties.

Comment: @Conrad the congruence $x(x-1)...(x-(p-1)) = x^p-x$ mod $p$ is equivalent to my question - but how to prove this?

Comment: Conrad wrote properly Polynomial x**(p-1)-1 has p-1 solutions in Zp group. 0 is not a solution. Hence, 1,2...,p-1 are solutions. How do I know it does not have less different solutions but some of order >=2? It follows from Euler's Theorem!. Hence, x**(p-1)-1=(x-1)*(x-2)*...*(x-(p-1)). As a result, we have Wilson's Theorem: For every prime p, (p-1)!=-1 modulo p.

Comment: @MaciejFicek That's nice! So from Euler's theorem (Fermat's little theorem) $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 (p)$ for $x=1,...,p-1$ we can factor $x^p-x \equiv x(x-1)...(x-(p-1))$ and we get that (a) the Stirling numbers of the first kind $s(p,k), 1<k<p$ are divisible by $p$ *and* (b) Wilson's Theorem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These coefficients are by definition the [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind) (see also [Coefficients of $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-k)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/643493/coefficients-of-x-1x-2-cdotsx-k)), as noted in comments. Now notice that $$x^{p} - x \equiv x(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)\cdots (x -(p-1))\pmod{p},$$ since left hand side is divisible by $p$ for all integers $x$ by Fermat's little theorem, as is the right hand side (it is a product of $p$ consecutive integers). And so
$$
[x^i]P(x)=[x^{i+1}](xP(x))\equiv[x^{i+1}](x^p-x)\pmod p,$$
and the result follows.

Comment: Well, the ideas of your answer are already in the comments ... but your answer is correct and complete :-) Actually I was looking for another way of prooving Fermat's little theorem, but I did not state that in my question. So actually I would still be interested in a proof of this divisibility property of Stirling numbers that does not use Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: How does the "Now notice that" follow from the "since"? The polynomial $f(x) = 0$ is also divisible by $p$ for all $x$, but it doesn't follow that $f(x) \equiv x^p-x$ *as polynomials*. I think you need to say a little more...